# Will the data from two different sources conflict in GCDAsyncSocket?

Tags: gcdasyncsocket

I've been trapped in this problem.

Briefly speaking,

I've got several devices. Each of them will send a pic to the server. Because of the size of pic, the data will be separate into several parts. So each time didReadData: method called, I should append the incoming data.

Here comes the problem:(

If two or more devices send pic to the server at same time, will the data conflicts?

I mean:

DEVICE1 will send data11 data12 data13

DEVICE2 will send data21 data22 data23

Is there any possibility that the data I gained is in this order: data11 data21 data12 ....(two bags of data just mixed up)?

Answer (score 1):

OK. I think that I didn't get clear about how TCP protocol works.

GCDAsyncsocket is a very powerful library. It performs an excellent multi-thread work. And what I was confused about this problem is just for the reason that I didn't understand TCP deeply.

For these two devices, GCDAsyncsocket will call readData: in two different thread. No conflict would happen. All you should do is to handle parts of the data by using tag.